# Can't Execute netsh Command in Java

Tags: java, command, execute, netsh

I am trying to execute a netsh command in Java. I wanna get available networks. I can run this code on cmd :

```
"netsh wlan show network mode=Bssid  > D:\\output.txt"
```

It works. When I try run this code in Java, it doesn't work.

```
 Process networks= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netsh wlan show network mode=Bssid  > D:\\output.txt");
```

How can fix do that?

Comment: doesn't work **HOW**?

Comment: nothing happens, it doesn't create txt but on cmd works fine

Comment: try to execute this command as administrator. Ex. open netbeans or eclipse as administrator ( if you are using these tools ).

Answer (score 0):

There is an exec-overload, where you may pass arguments as String-array.

Actually netsh.exe cannot deal with this.

Solution is to execute netsh inside a command line interpreter, like

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/Cnetsh wlan show network mode=Bssid  > D:\\output.txt"});
```

Anyway the command line interpreter is the only way to handle the output filter ´>´

Else, you might omit writing to a file and access the output immediately as String list

```
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(networks.getInputStream()));
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line;
    try
    {
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
        {
            res.add(line);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        x.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You would do this anyway to be synchronous with the called process.